# How to delete files cached in supporting files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I use the following code to store an NSMutableArray into a file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePathHit = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hit"];        
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.arrayHit toFile:filePathHit];
```

and the code below to retrieve data from the file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePathHit = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hit"];

NSMutableArray *unarchivedHit = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePathHit];
```

It works fine but the file been written to seems reside there all the time, so each time I relaunch my application, it reads data from there. But what I want to achieve is the data only resides there during the application operates, and once the app's shut down the data been cleared. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSFileManager](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2Fdocumentation%2Fcocoa%2Freference%2Ffoundation%2Fclasses%2Fnsfilemanager_class%2Freference%2Freference.html&ei=z-05U5W7AuyuyAHd3IDwCw&usg=AFQjCNHsIB61hhP-jWdTF16gaW7xA97-VQ&sig2=mpha45YmJLhsVz1OKArHig&bvm=bv.63808443,d.aWc):

```
NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePathHit error:&error];
```